# Imageview cropping mechanism best approach

Tags: android, algorithm, matrix, bitmap

What should be the ideal way to crop a 100 X 100 bitmap image from left side / centre side / right side in Android using co-ordinate system ?

Let's say the left side image crop would provide 1/3 rd of the image starting from co-ordinate 0,0 [bottom left] to 33,100 [top right]

right side cropped image will be 66,0 to 100, 100

centre side cropped image will be 33,0 to 66,0

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Glide or Fresco implementation of the crop. 
Fresco can do [custom crop](https://frescolib.org/docs/scaletypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to create a bitmap and crop that one by creating a new bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ...; // your Bitmap
Bitmap croppedBitmapLeft;
Bitmap croppedBitmapCenter;
Bitmap croppedBitmapRight;

// Left side
croppedBitmapLeft = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 33, 100);
croppedBitmapCenter = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 33, 0, 33, 100);
croppedBitmapRight = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 66, 0, 33, 100);
```

[See Bitmap.createBitmap() API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `bitmap` crop then try [Fresco](https://frescolib.org/docs/scaletypes.html) library.

Or if you have enough idea about image matrix, you can try this:

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
final Matrix matrix = imageView.getImageMatrix();
final float imageWidth = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
final int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
final float scaleRatio = screenWidth / imageWidth;
matrix.postScale(scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Or you can customise your `ImageView' Like:

```
public class ImageViewTopCrop extends ImageView
{
    public ImageViewTopCrop(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    public ImageViewTopCrop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    public ImageViewTopCrop(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        Matrix matrix = getImageMatrix();
        float scaleFactor = getWidth()/(float)getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 0, 0);
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
    }
}
```